# Limpar espaços em branco de um array

Tags: vb.net

Não estou achando a resposta p essa pergunta, simplesmente o que eu quero saber fazer é remover posições vazias de um array, por exemplo:

```
var(0) = "Remover"
var(1) = ""
var(2) = "espaços"
var(3) = ""
var(4) = "em"
var(5) = ""
var(6) = "branco"
```

Quero remover as posições vazias, que nesse caso seria var(1), var(3) e var(5),

Alguém saberia fazer isso?

Estava pensando em passar somente campos não vazios para outra array, mas como poderia fazer isso?

Tentei fazer da seguinte mandeira:

```
 Dim teste() As String
 Dim i1 As Integer = 1
 Dim i2 As Integer = 0
 Dim testesemespaco(500) As String

 teste = html.Split()

 While i1 < teste.Length

   If teste(i1) <> "" Then

        testesemespaco(i2) = teste(i1)

        i2 = i2 + 1

   End If

   i1 = i1 + 1

 End While
```

Comment: Não é possível remover posições de um `array`, eles têm tamanho fixo.

Comment: Nem se for tentar passar somente as posições que não estão vazias para uma outra array?

Comment: Aí sim, mas isso precisaria estar explícito na pergunta XD

Comment: vou editar, kkkk

Comment: você saberia fazer isso? eu estou tentando mas não ta indo

Comment: Sei sim. Vou fazer uma resposta

Comment: É um array de string?

Comment: sim, vou editar a pergunta colocando o meu código que não está funcionando

Comment: Me avise se funcionar ou não.

Comment: Apareceu um erro, http://prntscr.com/feb7gl

Comment: Falta um `.ToArray()` depois do Where. Veja minha edição

Comment: Agora foi, valeu ai mano !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer isso facilmente com LINQ, veja o exemplo.

Também vai ser possível fazer com um `for` passando por todos os elementos e criando outro `array` ou uma lista. Neste caso, seria bem melhor criar uma lista, porque elas têm alocação dinâmica, então não vai ser necessário fazer dois *loops* para deixar apenas os elementos válidos na coleção.

```
Dim array = New String() {"Remover", "", "espaços", "", "em", "", "branco"}
Dim novoArray = array.Where(Function(palavra) Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(palavra)).ToArray()

For Each p As String In novoArray
    Console.WriteLine(p)
Next
```

A expressão no `Where` diz o seguinte:

> "Para cada `palavra`, sendo `palavra` um elemento de `array` me retorne apenas aquela que não seja nula ou vazia".

[Veja funcionando no .NET Fiddle.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/209047)

Answer (score -1):

Augusto conforme disse acima está aqui o código adaptado para o modelo que o Autor Perguntou.

Sub Teste()

```
Dim Lista() As String
Dim Base As Worksheet
Dim Linha, i As Long
Dim Dado As String
Dim Lista_Atualizada() As String

' Instancia da base
Set Base = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Plan1.Name)

' Pega a ultima linha preenchida da base
Linha = Base.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

' Redimenciona a lista até a quantidade de linha
ReDim Lista(1 To Linha)

'Percorre a lista para pegar os dados
For i = 1 To Linha
    
    Lista(i) = Base.Cells(i, 1)

Next i

' Pega a lista de retorno com os dados Na posição certa
Lista_Atualizada() = Pegar_Apenas_Dados(Lista())
```

End Sub

Public Function Pegar_Apenas_Dados(Lista() As String)

```
' Variaveis de ambiente
Dim i, j, Linha As Long
Dim Lista_Retorno() As String
Dim Dado_Lista As String

Linha = 1

' Percorre a lista para saber quantas linhas preenchida tem na lista
For i = 1 To UBound(Lista)
    
    ' Pega a ordem de pagamento
    Dado_Lista = Lista(i)
        
    ' Verifica se o dado da lista é diferente de Vazio
    If Dado_Lista <> "" Then
        
        ' Se for eu incremento uma linha
        Linha = Linha + 1
    End If
    
Next i

' Redimenciona a linha
ReDim Lista_Retorno(1 To Linha)

' Limpo a variavel
Dado_Lista = vbNullString
Lin = 1

' Percorre a lista novamente
For i = 1 To UBound(Lista)
    
    Dado_Lista = Lista(i)
    
    If Dado_Lista <> "" Then
        Lista_Retorno(Lin) = Lista(i)
        Lin = Lin + 1
    End If
Next i

' Retorna os dados
Pegar_Apenas_Dados = Lista_Retorno()
```

End Function

Fico no aguardo de seu retorno

Atenciosamente

Rafael

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

Tente utilizar Essa função é algo simples mas funciona muito bem.

```
Public Function Pegar_Apenas_Dados(Lista() As String)
    
    ' Variaveis de ambiente
    Dim i, j, Linha As Long
    Dim Lista_Retorno() As String
    Dim Pagamento As String
    
    Linha = 1
    
    ' Percorre a lista
    For i = 1 To UBound(Lista)
        
        ' Pega a ordem de pagamento
        Pagamento = Lista(i, 1)
            
        ' Verifica se o pagamento é diferente de Vazio
        If Pagamento = "" Then
            Linha = i - 1
            Exit For
        End If
        
    Next i
    
    ' Redimenciona a linha
    ReDim Lista_Retorno(1 To Linha, 1 To Colun_)
    
    ' Percorre a lista novamente
    For i = 1 To Linha
        For j = 1 To Colun_
            Lista_Retorno(i, j) = Lista(i, j)
        Next j
    Next i
    
    ' Retorna os dados
    Pegar_Apenas_Dados = Lista_Retorno()
    
End Function
```

Comment: De onde surgiu essa `ordem de pagamento` ??? Não testei, mas esse código não parece atender a necessidade do AP. Veja Aqui `ReDim Lista_Retorno(1 To Linha, 1 To Colun_)` não faz sentido o array da pergunta é unidimensional e não bidimensional.

Comment: Peço perdão pelo meu equivoco, neste meu caso ele remove apenas todos os espaços em branco do final da Lista, mas como é uma questão adaptação achei que poderia ajudar.

Comment: Admiro a iniciativa, mas esse código está muito fora do contexto do autor da pergunta e não faz o que você imagina que faça. Na verdade ele nem funciona.